# Somar campos dinamicos em jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte HTML

```
<form id="FrmLoja" method="post" action="#">
  <input type="text" name="valor[]" id="valor" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="valor[]" id="valor" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="valor[]" id="valor" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="valor[]" id="valor" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="valor[]" id="valor" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="valor[]" id="valor" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="valor[]" id="valor" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="valor[]" id="valor" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="" />
</form>
```

Preciso somar todos os valores e inserir o resultado total, sem a necessidade de um reload na página... Este campo valor, é um campo dinâmico, onde eu tenho um btn (+) que adiciona uma nova linha sempre que preciso, dentro do array... Como eu posso fazer esta soma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz assim:

```js
 $('#add').click(function() {
  $('.fields').append('<input type="text" name="valor[]" id="valor" value="0" onkeyup="sum()" />');
});

function sum()
{
  let total = 0;
   
  $('.fields input').each(function() {
      total += +$(this).val();
  });
  $('#total').val(total);
}
```

```css
.fields input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="FrmLoja" method="post" action="#">
  <div class="fields">
    <input type="text" name="valor[]" id="valor" value="0" onkeyup="sum()"/>
  </div>

  <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="" />

  <button type="button" id="add">+</button>
</form>
```

OBS.: Deixei o evento como keyup só como exemplo, você pode altera-lo para onblur para que a soma seja feita só quando o usuário terminar de digitar e tirar o foco do campo.

Comment: Olá @JuniorNunes, tentei criar este exemplo no jsfield https://jsfiddle.net/u590wvLz/ mas não funcionou

Comment: @AndréBaill Foi problema com a declaração da função `sum`, ajeitei lá: https://jsfiddle.net/u590wvLz/1/